# Elasticsearch Pagination on List stored in a field

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I have a document with the following format:

```json
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tom",
    "items": [ "item_1", "item_2", "item_3",.....,"item_1000"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Rob",
    "items": [ "item_10001", "item_1002", "item_1003",.....,"item_2000"]
}]
```

```
Request
{
size:10,
page: 2,
id: 1,
documentId: 2
}
```

Expected response:
`{items: [item_10,......item_19]`

I'm trying to get a paginate list of the "items" field to retrieve 10 items for a provided `page_number` & ID but it is not working.

Is there is a way to paginate the elements of a given field in `ElasticSearch` using elasticSearch pagination techniques

Comment: as far as i know it is not possible to paginate the array elements. you can store that field as nested object and try it out using inner_hits for pagination.